# How to save page contents to string using webBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, i am trying to download a .txt file using a webBrowser.
This is what i have:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://comm.epizy.com/Users/" + textBox1.Text + @".txt");
MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
```

and even though the txt files just contains
"als
736c61", it always returns this:

[image]

How can i get it to display just the content? In this case, "als 736c61".

Comment: Use WebClient instead?

Comment: I thought of that, but it just tells me that i need to have JavaScript